# how can i turn on memu play remote debugging mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, debugging, emulation

**i get this error, whenever i try to turn on remote debugger in my memu play emulator, while coding react native, I'm a newbie, and I've been on this problem for ages, my server and expo go will automatically stop, and it's annoying**